# Not able to call service from angularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

I've defined 1 service to fetch the category and controller to call the service.

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    data: { action: 'GET' }
};


sampleApp.factory('SuperCategoryService', ['$http', function ($http){
    return {
        GetSuperCategories: function () {
            return $http(req)
                .then(
                function(response) 
                {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') 
                    {
                        alert ('right');
                        //return response.data;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        alert ('wrong');
                        // invalid response
                        //return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }

                }, 
                function(response) {
                    alert ('again worng');
                    // something went wrong
                    //return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
            }
        };
}]);


sampleApp.controller('SuperCategoryController', ['$scope', 'SuperCategoryService', function ($scope, SuperCategoryService){

    $scope.SuperCategories = function() {

        SuperCategoryService.GetSuperCategories()
            .then(function(d) {
                alert (d);
                if (d != undefined) {
                    alert ('in');
                    // Your data should be loaded here
                    console.log(d.data);
                    alert (d);
                    $scope.SuperCategories = d.data;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert ('Here');
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                // Errors here
            });
    }

}]);
```

Even though i am calling the service in controller, but its not hitting to any of the alert in service. (Not even error case)

What can be the problem? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling SuperCategories() from your template?? Did you try to open the DevTools to see if there is any error in your console??

Comment: you have to inject the factory in controller `function ($scope, SuperCategoryService){}` and then in controller use it like `SuperCategoryService.GetSuperCategories()`

Comment: You assigned the function to call your service to `$scope.SuperCategories` variable. Ok. Are you then invoking it anywhere? Right now, nowhere in your code that you posted you are invoking this function

Comment: @alphamikevictor There is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

See this [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation.Here you did a mistake in calling method of `$http`.

```
sampleApp.factory('SuperCategoryService', ['$http', function ($http){
    return {
        GetSuperCategories: function () {
            return $http.post('http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl',{ action: 'GET' });                                   
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo here http://jsbin.com/tahigerube/1/edit

you need to call your $scope.SuperCategories to execute it

```
...
   $scope.SuperCategories();
...
```